# How to rearrange data frame so that values in one column are row names?

Tags: r, dataframe, bioinformatics, transpose, tidyverse

I have a data frame containing 450K methylation beta-values for approx. 450 probes for two samples. This data is displayed in three columns, and looks like this:

```
>head(ICGC)
 submitted_sample_id    probe_id    methylation_value
1  X932-01-4D          cg00000029         0.6
2  X932-01-6D          cg00000029         0.4
3  X932-01-4D          cg00000108         0.3
4  X932-01-6D          cg00000108         0.7
5  X932-01-4D          cg00000109         0.9
6  X932-01-6D          cg00000109         0.1
```

I would like to rearrange this data.frame so that the probe IDs are the rownames and the sample IDs are the column names, so that it looks like this:

```
>head(ICGC_2)
           X932-01-4D    X932-01-6D 
cg00000029    0.6           0.4
cg00000108    0.3           0.7
cg00000109    0.9           0.1
```

I have tried:

```
>library(tidyverse)
ICGC_2 <- ICGC %>% remove_rownames %>% column_to_rownames(var = "probe_id")
```

But this didn't work as each probe ID in ICGC appears twice in the column (as there are two samples). I also tried:

```
hello <- data.frame(ICGC[,-2], row.names = ICGC[,2])
```

But this had the same problem. The reason I want to rearrange this data in this way is because I would like to convert the beta values to M-values and use this data as the object in cpg.annotate (available through Bioconductor package DMRcate) - cpg.annotate requires the object to have unique Illumina probe IDs as rownames and unique sample IDs as column names.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. `spread` funciton from the `tidyr` package is what you need.

```
library(tidyverse)

ICGC_2 <- ICGC %>%
  spread(submitted_sample_id, methylation_value) %>%
  remove_rownames() %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "probe_id")
ICGC_2
           X932-01-4D X932-01-6D
cg00000029        0.6        0.4
cg00000108        0.3        0.7
cg00000109        0.9        0.1
```

Data:

```
ICGC <- read.table(text = "submitted_sample_id    probe_id    methylation_value
1  'X932-01-4D'          cg00000029         0.6
2  'X932-01-6D'          cg00000029         0.4
3  'X932-01-4D'          cg00000108         0.3
4  'X932-01-6D'          cg00000108         0.7
5  'X932-01-4D'          cg00000109         0.9
6  'X932-01-6D'          cg00000109         0.1",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 2):

In base R you can do this:

```
wICGC <- reshape(ICGC, idvar = "probe_id", 
                       timevar = "submitted_sample_id", direction = "wide")
wICGC <- data.frame(wICGC[,-1], row.names=wICGC[,1])

wICGC

#            methylation_value.X932.01.4D methylation_value.X932.01.6D 
# cg00000029                          0.6                          0.4 
# cg00000108                          0.3                          0.7 
# cg00000109                          0.9                          0.1
```

Answer (score 1):

For a different perspective, you can also use `melt` in `reshape`.

```
library(reshape)
m <- melt(IGC, id=c("submitted_sample_id", "probe_id"))
cast(m, probe_id~submitted_sample_id)

> cast(m, probe_id~submitted_sample_id)
    probe_id X932-01-4D X932-01-6D
1 cg00000029        0.6        0.4
2 cg00000108        0.3        0.7
3 cg00000109        0.9        0.1
```